# Symfony 2 Kernel Interface handling request

Tags: php, symfony

I'm a little bit confused about Symfonys HttpKernelInterface handle() function: The doc says this function returns a response. But in my case it seems as if this function performs a redirect - and the redirect takes me to the login page - in every case.

So what I'm trying to do is to save a request to the session:

```
$request = $event->getRequest();
$data = serialize($request);
$this->_session->set('pl_lastUserRequest', $data);
```

Then there are a few other pages are shown. At a later time the request is transformed back to a request object and should be processed:

```
$request = unserialize($this->_session->get('pl_lastUserRequest'));
```

And now I thought i can pass that request-object to the handle function of the kernel - but doing so I will be redirected to the login page:

```
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
```

I tried to print out (for debugging) both objects, the request and the response. I can see that page for just one second and then the redirect starts. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think your response object is actually a `RedirectResponse`, so naturally you get redirected after outputting it. 

The reason you have a redirect is probably because you're trying to view it on firewalled page, so your request gets picked up by securitybundle and handled there.

Comment: Well, you're right. But I don't understand why I get to the login page for the firewall, because I'm logged in when I try to "handle" the request. Is there any option I have to set in order to stay logged in (Curious is that the rendered login page lokks as if I'm logged in...)